# How to remove everything before the first occurence of a comma in base64 string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a base64 string and I want to always remove the first part of it before sending it to an external database. I want it to remove everything before the first `/` or remove everything before the `,` and including the comma.

Ex.

`data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QisRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACg...`

return `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QisRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACg...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a substring you can do that, you get the 'base64,', add 7 and it returns you just the string.Also you can do a substring from the ','.

```
let data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QisRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACg';
    console.log(data.substring(a.indexOf('base64,')+7))

let data2 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QisRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACg';
 console.log(data.substring(a.indexOf(',')+1));
```